# Statistics question. Drawing cards without replacement. Every time you draw a certain card draw another.

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, recreational-mathematics, card-games

I'm looking for a series/function for this card game statistic.
I'll post a specific case to start but I'm looking for the general case.

Ex. You have a 10 card deck of 5 blue cards and 5 red cards. And you preform this action.  Draw a card if it is red preform this action again.

I know this is #cards drawn on average = [1+(5/10)+(5/10)(4/9)+(5/10)(4/9)(3/8)+(5/10)(4/9)(3/8)(2/7)+(5/10)(4/9)(3/8)(2/7)(1/6)]

But I am looking for a function for the general case with A deck of N blue cards and M Red cards.

Thank you very much for your Consideration.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? If you want to know the number of cards drawn until the first red, you can follow a [hypergeometric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution.

Comment: With $N$ blue cards and $M$ red cards, the average number of red cards drawn before the first blue card is $\frac M{N+1}.$ So the total number of cards drawn, up to and including the first blue card (assuming $N\gt0$) is (on average) one more than that.

Comment: Thats exactly it the hyper geometric dist. 100% thank you for that. My google fu was not working.